# Handle read exception without any packages

Tags: haskell

I'm writing a function that convert a string to a custom data type using read, but I need to throw an error if the string can't be cast into the custom data type. How do I do that without using any extra packages?

Comment: You can use `readMaybe`, it's in the base package which contains the most basic stuff, including the addition operator, so to speak. If you can't use that for some reason, use `reads` instead of `read` and pattern match the resulting list.

Answer (score 0):

For using `read` for converting a `String` in to you custom data you have to make your custom data a instance of `Read`.

For defining a instance of `Read`, if your custom data type is `A`, you have to implement de function `readsPrec` with type `Int -> ReadS A` that is equivalent to `Int -> String -> [(A, String)]`.

The `Int` is the precedence of the enclosing context and you can usually ignore it.

The `String` is the string that you are going to convert.

The result type `[(A, String)]` is a list that contains all possibly outputs of transforming the string (maybe none).

So what you probably have to do is define the function `readsPrec` to return `[]` when the string can't be cast and return a list with one element when you can cast it.